# Xamarin.Mac NSView DrawRect not called despite NeedsDisplay

Tags: macos, appkit, xamarin.mac

I am trying to create a view representing a vertical line that moves horizontally within another view.

I have the following ViewController and custom view.

```cs
using System;
using System.Timers;
using AppKit;
using CoreGraphics;

namespace CustomControlExperiment
{
    public partial class ViewController : NSViewController
    {
        private Timer _timer;
        private LineControl _lineControl;

        public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            var frame = new CGRect { X = 0, Y = 0, Height = ContentView.Frame.Height, Width = 1 };
            _lineControl = new LineControl(frame);

            ContentView.AddSubview(_lineControl);

            _timer = new Timer(500);
            _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
            _timer.Start();

        }

        private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            _lineControl.Position++;
        }
    }

    public class LineControl : NSView
    {
        private float _position;

        public LineControl(CGRect frameRect) : base(frameRect)
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            WantsLayer = true;
        }

        public override void DrawRect(CGRect dirtyRect)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DrawRect");
            base.DrawRect(dirtyRect);

            var context = NSGraphicsContext.CurrentContext?.CGContext;

            if (context == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var height = Frame.Height;

            context.SetStrokeColor(new CGColor(.5f, .6f, .7f));
            context.SetLineWidth(1f);
            context.SetLineDash(0, new nfloat[] { 3, 3 });

            context.MoveTo(0, 0);
            context.AddLineToPoint(0, height);

            context.StrokePath();
        }

        public float Position
        {
            get => _position;
            set
            {
                _position = value;
                Console.WriteLine("Position = " + _position);

                NeedsDisplay = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DrawRect is called once when the program is first run. After that it is not called again, despite Position being incremented and NeedsDisplay being set.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know if it's the cause of your issue, but your `System.Timers` `timer` elapsed event is run on a thread pool thread. It's not legal to set `needsDisplay` outside the main thread. If you try to do that in Xcode, you will get a runtime error from the thread sanitizer. You need to update `Position` from the main thread, or marshal the call to set `needsDisplay` onto the main thread.

Comment: This did cross my mind but hadn't investigated it yet as in other situations I had an exception. So it fails silently. Anyway, great stuff, thanks. Please post as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `System.Timers.Timer` elapsed event is run on a thread pool thread - it's not legal to set `needsDisplay` outside the main thread. If you try this in Xcode, it's a runtime error from the thread sanitizer.

You need to modify your code so that `Position` is updated from the main thread, or marshal the call to set `needsDisplay` onto the main thread.

There are various approaches to that in .NET and Xamarin - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/ios-ui/ui-thread) is one document suggesting to use `InvokeOnMainThread` (it's for iOS but I believe it applies to macOS also).